# Google Chart: How do implement individual category filter without binding them?

Tags: google-visualization

I have 3 category filter which doesn't want to bind them and act as an individual drop-down list. Is there any way to achieve? Thanks for your help. This is an initial code developed.

```
function formInitialization() {
            var sqlQuery = "sql?tq=select * &sqlQueryID=form_dropdown_data";
            var requestControlHandler = new google.visualization.Query(sqlQuery);
            requestControlHandler.send(responseControlHandler);
        }
        function responseControlHandler(queryControlResponse) {
            var filterProductTypes = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper(
            {
                'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
                'containerId': 'filterProductTypesContainer',
                'options': {
                    'filterColumnIndex': '0', 'ui': {
                        'label': '', 'labelSeparator': ':', 'labelStacking': 'horizontal', 'allowTyping': false, 'allowNone': false, 'allowMultiple': false
                    }
                }
            });

            var filterSupportLifecycle = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper(
            {
                'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
                'containerId': 'filterSupportLifecycleContainer',
                'options': {
                    'filterColumnIndex': '2',
                    'ui': { 'label': '', 'labelSeparator': ':', 'labelStacking': 'horizontal', 'allowTyping': false, 'allowNone': false, 'allowMultiple': false }
                }
            });

            var filterReleaseTypes = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper(
           {
               'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
               'containerId': 'filterReleaseTypesContainer',
               'options': {
                   'filterColumnIndex': '1',
                   'ui': { 'label': '', 'labelSeparator': ':', 'labelStacking': 'horizontal', 'allowTyping': false, 'allowNone': false, 'allowMultiple': false }
               }
           });
            var responseControlDataTable = queryControlResponse.getDataTable();
            var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));
            dashboard.draw(filterProductTypes, responseControlDataTable);
            //   initialization();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the `'dataTable'` property, then draw each control individually

see following snippet...

```
function responseControlHandler(queryControlResponse) {
  var filterProductTypes = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
    'containerId': 'filterProductTypesContainer',
    'dataTable': queryControlResponse.getDataTable(),
    'options': {
      'filterColumnIndex': '0',
      'ui': { 'label': '', 'labelSeparator': ':', 'labelStacking': 'horizontal', 'allowTyping': false, 'allowNone': false, 'allowMultiple': false }
    }
  });
  filterProductTypes.draw();

  var filterSupportLifecycle = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
    'containerId': 'filterSupportLifecycleContainer',
    'dataTable': queryControlResponse.getDataTable(),
    'options': {
      'filterColumnIndex': '2',
      'ui': { 'label': '', 'labelSeparator': ':', 'labelStacking': 'horizontal', 'allowTyping': false, 'allowNone': false, 'allowMultiple': false }
    }
  });
  filterSupportLifecycle.draw();

  var filterReleaseTypes = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
    'containerId': 'filterReleaseTypesContainer',
    'dataTable': queryControlResponse.getDataTable(),
    'options': {
      'filterColumnIndex': '1',
      'ui': { 'label': '', 'labelSeparator': ':', 'labelStacking': 'horizontal', 'allowTyping': false, 'allowNone': false, 'allowMultiple': false }
    }
  });
  filterReleaseTypes.draw();
}
```

**EDIT**

to set the default value for a CategoryFilter,

set the `'state'` property

`'state'` has one property --> `'selectedValues'`

`'selectedValues'` is an array of values that will be selected when drawn
(the values must exist in the list)

see following snippet...

```
  var filterProductTypes = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
    'containerId': 'filterProductTypesContainer',
    'dataTable': queryControlResponse.getDataTable(),
    'options': {
      'filterColumnIndex': '0',
      'ui': { 'label': '', 'labelSeparator': ':', 'labelStacking': 'horizontal', 'allowTyping': false, 'allowNone': false, 'allowMultiple': false }
    },
    'state': {
      'selectedValues': ['Default Value']
    }
  });
```

Comment: Sweet, Sweet. Nearly developed an alternative solution for this. Today i learned something. You are an inspiration.I thank you from the bottom of my heart.

Comment: Thank you. How to specify the default value of the list when it is drawn?

Comment: I got it. How about passing the dynamic values. Because, my query will return value from database which is one among the list and need to display that value as selected. Thanks again.

Comment: I figured it. Here is the code for dynamic values. Please correct me if i am wrong. 'state': {
                   'selectedValues': [others_value]
               } where others_value = 'Others'